# How to dismiss a view controller in a popover after touching a button that accepts a choice

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

In my current project, targeted for iOS 5.0 and up, I want to show a view with some buttons that let the user choose a layout for what is currently being drawn on the screen.

On iPhone & iPod Touch I let the choice view controller take over the entire screen by calling:

```
[self presentViewController:choiceController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

On iPad I show the same view controller's views in a popover by calling this:

```
    [self setChooseLayoutPopover:[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:choiceController]];
    [[self chooseLayoutPopover] setDelegate:self];
    [[self chooseLayoutPopover] setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 460.0)];        
    [[self chooseLayoutPopover] presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

In both cases I pass two dismiss blocks to the choice view controller, one for when a layout is actually chosen, and one for when the user cancels the operation. On iPad touching outside the bounds of the popover does indeed cancel it, on iPhone & iPod Touch I show a Cancel-button that also works.

On iPhone & iPod Touch my dismiss block for making a choice works by calling:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:[self dismissBlockDone]];
```

but on iPad `presentingViewController` is always nil, and even if I pass a pointer to my presenting view controller myself using the above call does nothing on iPad.

I did implement `-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` and set the presenting view controller as the delegate for the popover, and this method does get called when the user touches outside the popover, but I can not find what to call after the user actually touched a choice button. I can set the chosen value but I don't know how to get out of the popover afterwards.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't you call something like:

```
   [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

to dismiss the popover? Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: Yes, you are right: I now pass a pointer to the popover in my choice view controller so that it can dismiss itself programmatically. I do have to do some cleanup inside this controller as it will not call back to the delegate's dismiss method. But, it now works, thank you for clearing this up for me...

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
```

hope this helps!